# Probability of each number in dice after n rolls

Tags: probability, statistics

for example we threw a 6 sided dice 4 times. The first two throws yielded 1.The 3rd is 3. What is the probability of each number at the 4th try? I cant quite figure out the formula to use

Comment: Look up "statistical independence."  The prior numbers have no effect on the value on the 4th roll.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no work was shown by the author.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is still $\frac{1}{6}$ for all the numbers. If you doubt that the number $1$ is somehow less probable because it turned out twice earlier, think of it like this. While playing a game with a die, do you wonder about the number of times a certain number appeared in its lifetime. Or even the number that appeared in the last $20$ turns. Every turn is independent of each other and hence, the probability space is unchanged every time.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I thought there is a way to compute the probability of and 1 and 2 since we know that (2,4,5,6) has a probability of (1-(1/3)^4) in the 4th try